# How do I start solving this question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

[image]

I thought really hard about this question but I can't figure out how to start solving it. If it was given what $f$ was I could use $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ to prove it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you know what $f_x$ and $f_y$ mean?

Comment: @Clayton partial derivative of f with respect to x and y.

Comment: Do you know how to use the chain rule?

Comment: @Skip yes I do. We first differentiate with an intermediate variable and the with the independent variable right?

Comment: Correct. So use the chain rule, the problem tells you $f(r,\theta)=f(\,x(r,\theta),\,y(r,\theta)\,)$.

Comment: @Clayton This is the problem, I know the concept and when I saw this question, what I understood was that first I differentiate f with respect to x and then with respect to r. After that again differentiate f with respect to y and then with respect to r. And add the two to get the answer. But what is f?

Comment: There is some abuse of notation. For the purpose of such an exercise write $$\hat f(r,\theta):=f\bigl(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta)\bigr)\ ,$$ or similar.

Comment: Could some write first 2 steps or so, after that I think I can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is a function of $x,y$ and each of $x,y$ is a function of $r,\theta$, the chain rule says that

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} & = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\\
& = f_x \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r \cos(\theta)) + f_y \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r \sin(\theta)) \\
& = f_x \cdot \cos(\theta) + f_y \cdot \sin(\theta)
\end{align*}